# "Mum's the word" and "See no evil, hear no evil"

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

There is an eastern proverb (perhaps a Middle Eastern one, ) which is used to ask someone in a spoken manner to keep something as a secret and do not reveal that they have **seen or heard** anything. I know some equivalents for that, but I have no idea which one is used by Americans to convey this message?

Here is my list:

> **a.** [Mum's the word.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mum%27s+the+word)  
> **b.** [See no evil, hear no evil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_No_Evil,_Hear_No_Evil) (It is a very close phrasing to what I need.)

However, both sayings work for me and the only thing I need to make sure about is whether they are common in American English in my explained case.
If not, then what would be the closest AmE equivalent for that?

Comment: I'm not American, but I don't think (b) has the meaning you intend. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_wise_monkeys

Answer (score 3):

I also think that *see no evil, hear no evil* isn't suitable for this case.

Although *mum's the word* is used in American English, it is better to use *keep something under wraps*, [according to Ngram Viewer statistics](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mum%20%27%20s%20the%20word%2Ckeep%20_PRON_%20under%20_PRON_%20hat%2Ckeep%20_PRON_%20under%20wraps&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmum%20%27%20s%20the%20word%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20_PRON_%20under%20_PRON_%20hat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20_PRON_%20under%20wraps%3B%2Cc0).

[image: Ngram Viewer is showing comparison between usage of idioms]

You can [customize this yourself](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info#), and find other idioms [at Spellzone.com](https://www.spellzone.com/blog/Twenty_Five_Idioms_about_Keeping_and_Spilling_Secrets.htm).